# How to "move" a circle with $r=1$ and defined by $ax^2 + by^2 = q^2 +cx$ over the x-axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to have an equation in the form of 
$$ax^2 + by^2 = q^2 +cx$$ 
or
 $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{q^2+cx-ax^2}{b}}$$

such that

$$f(k)=0; f(m)=0$$

where the distance between $(m,0)$ & $(k,0)$ is 1 and where $m,k>1$ and the area under the curve above the x-axis is $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

In other words, I want to know if it's possible to move a function of a circle with radius $r=1$ over the x-axis

Comment: probably meant to change that "a" in the denominator to a "b"

Comment: Is it true that $a,b>0$?

Comment: If you want a circle, you must have $a=b$.

Comment: No, translating a unit circle along the $x$-axis is simple. The challenge here lies in the impossible task of constructing a circle of radius one (as you have in the title) that is bisected by the $x$-axis (per the area constraint), but intersects it at points that are only one unit apart ($|m-k|=1$).

Comment: Realized my mistake, thanks. The problem is now actually moot, bc you can't have a circle with an area of $\pi$ but with a  radius of 0.5 units